# CSS problems container show / align span / align title

Tags: html, css

I have 3 problems with my CSS, I have a space between two menus i don't know how to delete it : [space between 2 menus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Tt8E.png)

**2 PROBLEM :**

How could i align two span , one in front of the other :
[SPAN ALIGN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrMeU.png)

**3 PROBLEM :**
How do i Align my title so as he start at a position X : 
I Did  : `float: right` , but i want all titles started at one position [TITLE ALIGN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHVlS.jpg)

Here is my code :

```
#dataSourceContainerContent{
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px 20px;
}
#dataFiltres{
    float: right;
}
```

CODE : 
I generated my Html with JS , i have an object Accordion (UWA ELEMENT) , i call this fonction to construct my Menu  :

```
initAccordion:function(Acc){



            for(var i=0;i<this.dataSourceInfo["dataSource"].length;i++){


            Acc.addItem({title:'<span class="fonticon "'+Assets.sourceIcons.protein+'></span>'+'  '+'<input id="checkBox" type="checkbox"> '+this.dataSourceInfo["dataSource"][i].name
                +'  '+'<span class="'+App.views.remoteMonitor.subviews.DataSourceContainer.dataSourceContainerTitle.dataSourceURL+'">'+this.dataSourceInfo["dataSource"][i].URL+'</span>'
                });

            Acc.setContent(i,this.setContentItem(this.dataSourceInfo["dataSource"][i]));

            }
        },
        setContentItem:function(Elem){ 

            var contentItem=UWA.createElement('div',{ 
                id:App.views.remoteMonitor.subviews.DataSourceContainer.dataSourceContainerContent.ids,
                identifier:'dataSourceContainer',
                reference: 'dataSourceContainer' 
             });
            contentItem.hide();
            var contentItemDataSets=UWA.createElement('span',{ 
                id:App.views.remoteMonitor.subviews.DataSourceContainer.dataSourceContainerContent.dataSets,
                identifier:'dataSourceContainerDataSets',
                reference: 'dataSourceContainerDataSets' 
             });


                for(var j=0;j<Elem["dataSets"].length;j++){
                    contentItemDataSets.addContent('</br>'+Elem["dataSets"][j].name);
                }
            var contentItemDataFilters=UWA.createElement('span',{ 
                id:App.views.remoteMonitor.subviews.DataSourceContainer.dataSourceContainerContent.dataFiltres,
                identifier:'dataSourceContainerDataFiltres',
                reference: 'dataSourceContainerDataFiltres' 
            });
```

Comment: show code not picuters

Comment: `Here is my code :` where is this code??

Comment: show also your html in snippet

Comment: I generate my html with JavaScript

Comment: so show that in snippet

Comment: is it clear now ?